# How to tell subject and predicative apart?

Tags: sentence-structure, semantics, subject, nominative

In a recent post, a rule of thumb has been given to tell subject and predicative apart, which, initially, because of both being in nominative, I thought would impossible. Namely:

> ["replace the verb with *kann betrachtet werden als*". If that doesn't kill the meaning, you got the subject.](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/34901/1691) (*)

It seems legit. However, it strikes me that you have to appeal to sense-making, while the syntax should be able to detect the subject by itself, as is, for instance, in the following two sentences:

> Gras isst der Hase.
>
> Den Jäger isst der Hase.

In both sentences the noun *Hase* **is** the subject. That has nothing whatsoever to do with making sense.

Is there an alternative rule to (*) that is independent of semantics?

Comment: Note the rule of thumb (which was mine) does *not always work* - Gertrude Stein's *Eine Rose ist eine Rose ist eine Rose*, for example, refuses to be solved with it. But I doubt a clear decision on which rose is the subject can be made at all, which is the whole point of this sentence.

Comment: Also note that syntax alone definitely is not able to detect the subject by itself: "Das Gras isst das Tier. Das Tier isst das Gras". You *need* to know that grass is not carnivorous to identify the subject.

Comment: The quoted rule explicitly referred to sentences of the type *Something is something* (Gleichsetzungsnominativ). Your sentences are *Something eats something*. Both the *Gleichsetzung* through *ist* and the second nominative are missing (the second noun – *Gras* and *Jäger*, respectively – is in the accusative case).

Comment: Incidentally, if there is only one nominative in the sentence, there is no difficulty in identifying the subject – it's the noun in the nominative case, making any application of the quoted rule beside the point for anything else than the *Gleichsetzungsnominativ*.

Comment: And finally, when it's ambiguous which noun is in the nominative (which is quite rare), you rely on semantic parsing, as @dirkt noted, but also on standard word order being used. So, in *Katze beißt Hund* and *Hund beißt Katze*, it's always the first noun that's the subject.

Comment: @Lebenita: No, the subject doesn't have to be the first noun. One expects that because it's the "natural" order, but any order is correct.

Comment: *Den Hund beißt die Katze*. There's no difference when articles are omitted - except that the meaning becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @tofro, dirkt: The rule that mandates that *Katze* is the subject in *Katze beißt Hund* is not one of grammar, but one of effective communication as evidenced by any number of newspaper headlines (of which this kind of shorthand is typical). I would welcome just one example of a gramatically ambiguous news headline where the first noun is *not* the subject.

Comment: @c.p.: Apologies for misreading your example sentences, which in fact exemplify the use of syntax to identify the subject. This is the normal case in German; only very rarely do you have to resort to non-syntactical information to establish the parts of a sentence. In those rare cases, you turn to conventions of communication (like customary word order) and semantics (in that order, I would argue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. Surface syntax deals with things such as concord or word order, and as the previous question pointed out, these indicators are non-conclusive for the *Gleichsetzungsnominativ*.

To be sure there are additional surface features that can be decisive in individual cases. For instance,

> Der Wal ist ein Säugetier.

almost certainly has "Wal" as the subject, since it would be weird to explain an indefinite noun phrase by referring to a definite noun phrase. But such indicators are only *sufficient* and not *necessary*, since you can easily make up examples which don't have them.